# Import data into JTable from text file

Tags: java, swing

I have an already created JTable in which I want to insert the data from a text file. I do not want to create another new JTable, but rather to insert the data into the correct rows and columns.

My purpose for all of this is that I want to save the JTable data before exiting the app and after re-opening the app I want the data to appear as I left it. I managed to export the JTable data to a text file before exiting, but the data won't show when I import from the text file.

Here is my code for exporting into the text file:

The if statements in the for loops are for checking whether the JTable field is empty or not.

```java
public void serializeData() {
   try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\X\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\data.txt"));
        for (int i = 1; i < dataTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < dataTable.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                if (dataTable.getValueAt(i, j) != null) {
                    writer.write(dataTable.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + " ");
                } else {
                    writer.write(0);
                }
            }
           writer.write("\n");
        }

        writer.close();
        System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /tmp/employee.ser");
    } catch (IOException i) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
    }
}
```

Here is my code to import from the text file:

At importing I want to import only the numbers in the text file, otherwise, I want to set the field empty.

```java
String filepath = "C:\\Users\\X\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\data.txt";
File file = new File(filepath);

 try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    Object[] lines = reader.lines().toArray();

    for(int i = 1; i<lines.length-1; i++) {
        String[] row = lines[i].toString().split(" ");
        for(int j = 1; j<row.length; j++) {
            if(row[i].equals(" ")) {
                dataTable.setValueAt(null, i, j);
            } else {
                dataTable.setValueAt(Double.parseDouble(row[j]), i, j);
            }
        }
    }

} catch(Exception ex) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
}
```

When I try to import the data from the text file, nothing appears in the JTable. 
How could I fix this?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if(row[i].equals(" ")) {
            dataTable.setValueAt(null, i, j);
        } else {
            dataTable.setValueAt(Double.parseDouble(row[j]), i, j);
        }
```

You basic logic is wrong. If you are importing data, that means you should be starting with an "empty" model. So you need to add each row of data as you parse it in your file.

So the logic should be something like:

```
if(row[i].equals(" ")) {
    row[i] = null;
} else {
    row[i] = Double.parseDouble(row[i]);
}

tableModel.addRow( row );
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working. The data still doesn't show.

Answer (score -2):

Call fireTableStructureChanged on your table model after updating the data.

Comment: You mean when im importing the data from the file? I tried it but the data still does not show up, only my table's cells size got bigger.

Comment: (1-) you should never invoke the fireXXX methods externally. These methods will be invoked by the TableModel.